# JQuery or Javascript: iterate through array with days of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing an app in Electron: I have 7 < div> elements for each day of the week, and they are given ids of #btn-SUNDAY, #btn-MONDAY, etc.

When any of them are clicked on, these buttons should change the text property of a < p> element, with the id of #day, to whichever day of the week the user clicked on.

My guess was to iterate through an array with all 7 days, and then compare which day was equal to #btn-[i], then change #day's text property to the string at the index.

While I'm able to change the text property, I always get "SATURDAY, and -1" as a result. I am obviously doing something very wrong. I could probably write this code out with if statements for each div, but I wanted to save time. Ironically, I've been at this for a while, and the solution is probably dead easy, and I just don't see it.

Here's my code snippet, which is included in the html page with the < div>s:

```
var days = [];
days.push('SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY');

for (i in days){

  $("#btn-"+days[i]).mouseup(function() {

    $("#day").text(`${days[i]}, and ${days.indexOf(i)}`);

  })
}
```

I'm guessing is I need an if statement somewhere in there, but heaven help my brain, I don't know where.

I might also be using the "for (i in x)" syntax improperly. Still trying to get a feel for Javascript and JQuery.

Any help is appreciated,

-Jon

Comment: Remember that i is going to be a string and not an integer. days is an array and not an object (hash) so you should retrieve with an integer index. I would use a for loop and index using the counter.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/voyijuq/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for your comment and effort! Unfortunately, though, my brain wasn't able to think of how to apply this information to my situation, but it is all very good advice and material. I will ponder on this

Comment: With javascript objects you can refer to a property like o["MyProperty"] to retrieve the value there. In an array you should use an integer to access a specific element. So to retrieve 'SUNDAY' from your array you would want days[0]. days["SUNDAY"] won't work and that is what your code is doing in your for loop.

Comment: OH, so you mean that the variable i in "for (i in days)" is a string, because it matches the array's type? If so, that makes sense!

Then you're right, I should have used a classic for loop. I'm more of a C++ coder, so I thought that the shorter syntax would do the same thing. I was assuming that i would be an integer, and that's why I got those problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a closure, and using jQuery's `each` seems to fit here

```js
var days = ['SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY'];

$.each(days, function(i, day) {
  $("#btn-" + day).on('mouseup', function() {
    $("#day").text(day + ', and ' + i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-MONDAY">Monday</button>
<button id="btn-TUESDAY">Tuesday</button>
<button id="btn-WEDNESDAY">Wednesday</button>
<br /><br />
<p id="day"></p>
```

Comment: Perfect! I was able to modify this exactly to my needs. Many thanks!